# Carry Non-Na-Values for more than one column forward based on two columns

Tags: dataframe

I am looking for the following solution.

I want to carry my Non-NA-Values forward but only within my column Name within the rows C or A AND for multiple columns.

Does anyone know how to solve this? :)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `dplyr` and the `fill` function from `tidyr`. You need to group by to make sure you only fill with values from the correct key.

`fill` fills missing values by using the previous entry so make sure the data is in the order you want to.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Key) %>% 
  fill(Value)

  Key   Date    Value  col4  col5
  <chr> <chr>   <int> <int> <int>
1 A     2001-06    NA    NA    NA
2 A     2001-07     2     2    NA
3 A     2002-08     2     1     1
4 C     2000-03     1    NA    NA
5 C     2000-05     1     1    NA
6 C     2000-07     2     2    NA
```

Comment: @Peter, you can fill multiple columns in one go. just add them to the fill statement. The dates need to be in order (or grouped), otherwise you might fill a month with a value from a later month.